# Xamarin Editor not showing keyboard in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am totally new to xamarin,

Following is my code :

```
<ListView x:Name="boxActivitiesList" ItemTapped="boxActivitiesList_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="25" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                              <Label Text="{Binding Box}" TextColor="BlueViolet" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                              <TableView IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <TableRoot>
                                        <TableSection>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="15,0">
                                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" Text="Remarks" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                                    <Editor x:Name="txtRemarks" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Editor>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                     </TableSection>
                                </TableRoot>
                           </TableView>
                          <Button x:Name="btnSave" Text="Save" Clicked="btnSave_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding BoxId}" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"></Button>
                         </StackLayout>
                   </ViewCell>
             </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

When I click on `Editor`, Keyboard does not show. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Xamarin can be a little finicky, this is not an answer, but have you tried just removing the complexity and seeing if it works? I.e try your editor in the first stack layout without the table. Also what device are you testing this on, ios uwp or andriod?

Comment: Yes! Without Listview and Table it is working fine and I am testing it on Android.

Comment: What about just without table? Also table inside a listview doesn't seem like a good design with the current example

Comment: Yes! Without table, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `Editor` is not working in the `Table`, however i would reconsider this design and just use a `Grid` to realize a more complex layout inside your parent `ViewCell`.

Although there should be nothing wrong with the way you have it, it does seem to be overly complicating things with more nested controls when its not really needed. Ergo, the nested table should really just be a layout like `Grid` or `StackPanel`

Lastly, *Xamarin.Forms* can be a little fickle at the best of times with the various devices it supports. so its best to keep things as simple as possible

Comment: Thank you very much, It starts working when I replaced TableView with Grid.